# Laptop Battery: Can I use 14.7v battery instead of 10.8v?

Tags: laptop, battery, lithium-ion, replacement

I'm using an HP G5 245 laptop and want to replace the OEM battery, which has a capacity of 47WH @ 10.8v (P/N: `HSTNN-PB6V TPN-1124 844198-850 MI06`):
[image: Screenshot]

- I couldn't find a 10.8v battery, but found some info that we can swap a 10.8v battery for an 11.1v; is this true and will it affect my laptop?

I [found](https://www.flipkart.com/lapex-807611-831-4-cell-laptop-battery/p/itmfgdsfhhbtwutg?pid=ACCFGDFXZQ9QNKFA&lid=LSTACCFGDFXZQ9QNKFAZJAUYI&marketplace=FLIPKART) a battery online and need help determining if it's compatible, as it's 53WH @ 11.1v:

- Will it affect my system, such as a difference in performance?

Answer (score 2):

No!  The system might work but likely won't due to the different charging requirements.

Worse then that - assuming the higher voltage battery will fit (I would hope it wouldn't) it can do damage to your laptop.  Higher maximum currents and/or WH values are OK - arguably beneficial, but higher voltages are problematic unless the laptop is designed to handle them.  From the little I've seen online of your laptop this is not the case here.

Comment: Thanks for your info!